# Finding who has used my private API in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I have deployed an API in Google Cloud and I have configured it to use API key. The API will be called by applications sitting under different Google Cloud projects. I have also enabled  other projects to create API key for themselves. When the API gets called by any application, I can see the API key that was used in logs but I can't see which project has created that key. My requirement is to know which project has created the API key. Is there any way to include the project owning that API key in the logs? or is there any way I can find the mapping between the API key and Google project?

Comment: I have been looking this up on the documentation but I wasn't able to find anything relevant nor closely related to this, which means that you probably can't and that you should be the one responsible of tracking each of the generated API keys. If you want me to investigate further it would prove useful to have some reproduction steps that I can follow.

Comment: I have been looking up the documentation as well but without any luck. Infact I read that you can't get project details in log. Hence I was looking for a way to map API key to project somehow. If I let other projects generate the key and can't find who generated it I don't have a way to know who used my API. Other option of generating  the keys for them means I won't be able to offer real self serve environment. I will provide steps in next post

Comment: I created an API using  quick start guide https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-endpoints. Then I modified the openapi_with_ratelimit.ymal and app_template.ymal to include details of my API.  Then enabled the API from another project by going in APIs and Services -> library ->private API. select the API and go to credentials. Generate API key from this screen. You can call your API using this key. Go to end points for the first project and check logs. You should see the entry for your call with the API key under payload. But there is no project.

Comment: I don't know how are you currently allowing other projects to create an API key, but maybe you should handle the logic of it on your code and store the keys with a project ID, so you can keep the trace of it.

Comment: I was reproducing your scenario but when searching for "private API" I encounter many results, could you be more precise?